# How does git choose a commit to checkout in its submodules?

Tags: git

I'm dealing with a large existing repo at work that has many submodules. I've noticed that when I do

```
git submodule update --checkout
```

Some of the modules checkout a specific commit (not the head of the branch)

```
git submodule update --checkout --force
Submodule path 'build/cmake': checked out '8ed3354a70974ec775eee94cdce57810deeda65f'
```

**My question is: Why does it pick that commit?**

My .gitmodules does not specify a commit or branch, and neither does .git/config.

Comment: More info: It turns out the commit does refer to a specific branch, but not one I have tracked in any config file

Comment: *Every* submodule specifies one specific commit, by ID.  This is the nature of Git's submodules.  The ID is recorded in the actual commit.  If the superproject is on branch `master` and `master` is currently commit `a1234567`, then Git examines `a1234567:build/cmake`, which is a tree entry of type "gitlink" and name `8ed335...`, and that's the commit that gets checked out (as a detached HEAD) in the submodule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference for the submodule in the current repository is both to the submodule, and a specific commit. That commit SHA is stored in the index.

If you were to change what commit the submodule HEAD is at, you would see a pending change in the parent repository. If you diff that change all you'll see is that the commit being referenced by the submodule is different, not any differences IN the submodule.

e.g.

`cd submodule
git reset --hard HEAD~4
cd ..
git status`

will yield

`-Subproject commit <old submodule HEAD SHA>
+Subproject commit <SHA of 4 commits before old HEAD>`

This is actually why submodules are kind of a pain to use. You can't specify that it should follow a branch, or be a specific tag. If you make changes in the submodule you have to commit and push there, then commit and push in the parent repository as well to update the referenced SHA. If you forget to push the submodule, but push the parent, then everyone else is going to get an error if they try to update the submodule. If you forget to commit the change to update the submodule commit to the parent, then no one else will pull your changes to their submodule.